# Got stuck on a glitch due to downloading same browser from two different Places

Tags: browser, brave

I have Brave as my default Browser downloaded long ago from the MS Store. During my browsing, I used to customize some settings from the regedit, PowerShell, browser settings or by adding extensions etc.

So few days ago I downloaded Brave, again but this time from the site. It finally got downloaded. But this time, an error occurred. One of the extensions, which is used to restrict the number of tabs, stopped working. Another extension, which blocks some specific sites, repeatedly refreshes, starts and closes in a loop, such that it occurs only after the no. of tabs restricted has exceeded, the specified on the previous extension.

The PC is showing only one Brave browser in settings. The Important files show that the last modification was done on the day of installation of site site-downloaded browser.

So What should I do now? And How should I get rid of the site-downloaded browser? Will it increase the space occupied on my PC? (Remember that: I have some settings customized on PowerShell and regedit, which I don't want to be lost) (Other browser-related people can also answer)

Comment: What is version number from "downloaded long ago from the MS Store", and what is version number of the new browser?  Did you take a note of the changes you did using regedit, Powershell, browser settings and ... ??

Comment: Yup, the last version was 120.1.61.109 and the new one is v1.61.109, think so both same

Comment: I think you simply need to redo installing those extensions, and other stuff that you did in the last couple of days.

Comment: Yesterday, I tried to do so but nothing has changed. Infact I also uninstalled Brave and then reinstalled it from MS Store, then also nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Store apps are installed in a different way, and to different locations, from regular Windows executables. Even though it appears to be the same Brave browser on the outside, "under the hood" things are different.

The *safest* thing to do is as follows.

- Make a list of all extensions and customizations.
- [Back up the entire profile.](https://community.brave.com/t/export-settings/144464)
- [Export all logins.](https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-export-passwords-bookmarks/41535/6) (This is a "belt-and-suspenders" approach.)
- Completely uninstall the Brave browser downloaded from their site.
- Completely uninstall the Brave browser downloaded from the Microsoft Store.
- Reinstall *one* version, either one directly from the authors of the software, or the version through a middleman.
- You now have the choice of:

  - Trying to reimport the logins, and then modifying your new profile
  - Or *replacing* the new profile with the old, *broken* profile and trying to fix it.

Comment: Is there any other alternative, I can't delete both because In regedit>local_machine>software>policies I have changed owner and permission to System only. So If I remove both then I can't access or customize it again. The link to that problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77373001/accidentlly-changed-permissions-to-system-only-with-ownership-to-system-in-reged

Comment: I just want to remove the site one or to restore the previous one.